# overlay imageview without pushing layouts down

Tags: android

a picture is worth a thousand words, so my question should basically be self-explanatory with the attached image: How to get rightmost screen instead of the center screen?

turns out i cannot attach images directly yet, so i have to link to it right now:

[How to get rightmost screen instead of the center screen?](http://db.tt/FK5fu7r)

just to add, i realise that it is not really possible to have the framelayout NOT expand as shown in screen 2b, but my question remains as to how to achieve such an overlay without pushing the Other layouts down i.e. the bottom part of the imageview would be on top of the top right part of the other layouts

Comment: perhaps you could have the image you are dynamically adding be outside the frame layout. ie have a relative layout contain both framelayouts and the imageview

Comment: thanks, it worked! i had to get the z-order right and things, but the master relativelayout did the trick. p.s. how do i accept your comment as the solution?

Comment: don't worry about it.  i think i needed to add it as an answer rather than a comment.  glad it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

perhaps you could have the image you are dynamically adding be outside the frame layout. ie have a relative layout contain both framelayouts and the imageview – jkhouw1 1 hour ago